# Mount partitions before apache starts (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: partitioning, mount, 20.04, apache2

I've created virtual hosts and log folders on other partition. I've set automount partitions when system starts, but I noticed that apache runs first (before partitions are mounted), so it doesn't see the path to VHs and log folder, and it doesn't load because of that error. Each time I have to restart manually apache. I know that if apache would load a bit later after the drives are mounted then I wouldn't have that error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "automount" ? Did you edit /etc/fatab to mount the partitions or did you do something else ?

Comment: I didn't adit fstab file directly, I used Disks app for that. Everything mounts fine the path is correct but I only need to restart apache every time after system boots up.

Comment: and by automount I mean mount at startup

Comment: does the partition(s) you want to wait for show up if you do `systemctl list-units --type=mount` .... if so can you provide the UNIT name?

Comment: I've never had this problem on ubuntu 14.04 (my previous version of ubuntu I used). I used there the same configuration of VH and their logs. Apache was loading as one of the last processes when system booted up. Maybe there is a way to slow down apache to start?

Comment: did you execute the suggested commands and look for the desired information?

Comment: yes there are these units and are loaded, active and mounted, but this is not a problem when I start apache manually after system is booted up it works fine. The problem is when apache wants to start while system is booting, it has problem to see the path of mounted partitions and therefor it stops loading and shows the error "document root does not exists", but as I said if I start apache manually after system is booted its works. That means apache wants to load before partitions are mounted.

Comment: I read the question and I know the problem... I asked "if so can you provide the UNIT name?".......  i will just put down what i have for an answer and let you add/figure the detail from there. `systemctl status apache`

Edit the location of the loaded service to include the unit names as the After values

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking me, but this is from the units' list: `media-user-WWW.mount    loaded active mounted /media/user/WWW` and this is one of the lines of command status apache when is active: failed `apachectl[706]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/media/user/WWW/MOJA/] does not exist` I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run
`systemctl status apache(or apache2)`

`sudo vi /the/file/from/Loaded:/line/apache.service`

add media-user-WWW.mount to the "After=" line.

save and exit

Comment: Thank you very much and for your patient in comments! :-)